# SQL Server - Query cancellation in "async_network_io" state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, llblgenpro, async-network-io

One of our customers has a very high performance server with SQL Server 2012, capable of processing large amounts of data in a very short time.
Unfortunately, the network does not seem to be as efficient.
As a client, users can set filters and query a view using LLBLGen (ORMapper).
The view has many fields but is a simple set of INNER JOIN. Over long periods it returns large amounts of data.
Client side the operator can also manually cancel the query in progress.
Everything works properly under normal conditions.

The particular problem is when a query is in progress from the client and, manually, the operator decides to interrupt it: in these conditions the SQL process remains alive and blocks the tables until the client application is closed.
In detail the condition is that:

- The query goes into "async_network_io" within a few seconds and stays there for tens of seconds. In other words, processing is much
  faster than transferring information.
- If the query is cancelled BEFORE it goes into the "async_network_io" state, the deletion is successful.
- If the query is cancelled DURING the "async_network_io" state, the
  process seems to go to block.

We are able to systematically re-create it, but we have no idea how to intervene and whether it is a SQL, network or LLBLGen problem.
We also tried to update the project's .NET Framework (the original was with .NET 2.0), but the result seems the same.

Any advice on this?

Comment: Despite the name, `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` typically as nothing to do with the actual network. It means, no more and no less, that SQL Server is waiting for an async network I/O operation to complete, typically as a result of the client not processing data that it's handed quickly enough. If the operation "hangs", this suggests that either SQL Server or the client are running into a deadlock condition where one part has issued a cancellation, but the other part isn't aware of it (and thus sending the result set never finishes, and locks remain in place).

Comment: To exclude SQL Server as the culprit, try repro'ing this on a SQL Server 2017 instance (LocalDB/Express is free); I assume the size of the data is not actually a factor here.

Comment: The problem would therefore be to search for in the ORMapper?
The client makes calls from a secondary thread. The deletion consists of a simple abort of the thread, within which it executes all the dispose of the objects and connections.

Comment: So the problem could be related to the SQL Server version?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely wrong. The correct way to cancel is calling `SqlCommand.Cancel()`, which will generate an exception in the code processing the results (which can be cleanly handled if you first set a flag, then check for that afterwards, as the resulting error looks scary). Aborting a thread either does nothing (because managed code will patiently wait until the thread is at a safe spot to do so) or leave your application in an inconsistent state. What's more, the SQL classes are not by default thread safe; only a very few things can be done from multiple threads, cancelling being one.

Comment: In fact, disposing the connection while SQL Server still believes an active result set is present on the connection could very well explain why this never finishes -- the client will probably wait for the dismantling of the session to happen, which SQL Server will never do because there's an active command which is still in progress.

Comment: The management of the thread I described is the one expressly indicated by LLBLGen documentation. I would expect them to automatically manage these aspects.
LLBLGen unfortunately does not allow direct access to the underlying connection objects.
If the problem is the call to "SqlCommand.Cancel ()" I deduce it is a problem of this ORMapper. I ask them for clarifications.
Thanks for the suggestion